# Deleting Firebase values on a SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I am trying to delete a value from the Firebase Realtime Database, just by swiping on a the list row but I am encountering a lot of problems, for example, when I delete a row, on the Firebase Realtime Database an object with a different id is deleted, I have the following code running when the swipe occurs (Sorry for the lot of prints but I was trying to understand the flow on my program :D):

EDIT: I am wondering how I can retrieve the value of the row in the List and by that using this extension:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func someKey(forValue val: Value) -> Key? {
        return first(where: { $1 == val })?.key
    }
}
```

And this is the delete code.

```
.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                                locali.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                                Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
                                    print(auth.currentUser?.email)
                                    print(indexSet.count)
                                    print(indexSet.startIndex)
                                    print(indexSet.endIndex)
                                    var indexCounter: Int = indexSet.first!
                                    //MARK: - delete
                                    ref
                                        .child("locali")
                                        .child(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "no uid")
                                        .child("nomeLocale\(indexCounter)")
                                        .removeValue (completionBlock: { (error, refer) in
                                            if error != nil {
                                                print(error)
                                            } else {
                                                print(refer)
                                                print("Child Removed Correctly")
                                            }
                                        })
                                    //MARK: - refactor
                                    Task {
                                        var dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot
                                        var refactoredWholeList: [String : NSObject]
                                        do {
                                            dataSnapshot = try await ref
                                                .child("locali")
                                                .child(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "no uid")
                                                .getData()
                                            print(dataSnapshot)
                                            guard var wholeList = dataSnapshot.value as? [String : NSObject] else {
                                                print("error with the guard first inside onDelete")
                                                return
                                            }
                                            var indexCounterDelete: Int = 0
                                            
                                            print("before changing indexes ----> \(wholeList) <----\n")
                                            for indexDelLocale in wholeList {
                                                print("This is the indexDelLocale ==> \(indexDelLocale)")
                                                print("indexCounterDelete: \(indexCounterDelete)")
                                                if var entry = wholeList.removeValue(forKey: indexDelLocale.key) {
                                                    print("Trying to sobstitute the index: \(indexDelLocale.key)")
                                                    print("With: \("nomeLocale\(indexCounterDelete)") for ==> \(entry)")
                                                    try await ref
                                                        .child("locali")
                                                        .child(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "no uid")
                                                        .updateChildValues(["nomeLocale\(indexCounterDelete)" : entry])
                                                }
                                                print("List count ==> \(wholeListRefactored.count)\n")
                                                if wholeList.count == indexCounterDelete {
                                                    print("RETURN")
                                                } else {
                                                    indexCounterDelete += 1
                                                }
                                            }
                                            print("\nafter changing indexes ----> \(wholeList) <----")
                                            print("This is the wholeListRefactored ==> \(wholeListRefactored)\n")

                                        } catch {
                                            print("error while retrieving the wholeList")
                                        }
                                    } //: Task
//                                    //MARK: - reupload
//                                    for locale in wholeListRefactored {
//                                        ref
//                                            .child("locali")
//                                            .child(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "no uid")
//                                            .updateChildValues([locale.key : locale.value])
//                                    }
                                }
                            }) //: onDelete
```

Comment: I wouldn’t try to delete in Firebase based on index. Instead, get the ids of your local objects that were selected for deletion and delete by id in Firebase

Comment: @jnpdx yep but how I can retrieve the text of the row? so that I can retrieve the key and delete the selected item?

Comment: You aren’t showing enough code to answer that. It’s not even clear what the array is that you’re displaying. Maybe locali? Just get those items by index if so

Comment: The problem with the question; we have no idea what your structure is so `wholeList = dataSnapshot.value as? [String : NSObject]` is meaningless to us. More importantly: don't do that; objects in code should represent the data stored in firebase. For example, a UserClass object that stores a key (the uid), firstName, lastName etc. When data is read from Firebase instantiate those objects and store in an array. Use *that* array as the tableView dataSource. When the user swipes a row, read the User object at that index from the array, that object contains the node key then delete from Firebase.